# How to host node.js app on google cloud propertly?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to host this https://github.com/idiidk/kahoot-tools  on google cloud. It works when i test it in cloud shell but when i deploy it it crashes. 
I see this error when i go to my app:

> Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not
>   complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds.

In google cloud i see this error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'express' at
>   Function.Module._resolveFilename
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15) at Function.Module._load
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25) at Module.require
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17) at require
>   (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18) at Object.
>   (/srv/kahoot-tools.js:8:21) at Module._compile
>   (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30) at
>   Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32) at
>   tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12) at
>   Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)

Answer (score 1):

express package is missing in "dependencies" of `package.json`. just add the following:

```
"express": "^4.16.3"
```

and also add this node for deploying to App Engine, otherwise dependencies won't get installed:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node kahoot-tools.js"
  }
```